# error response for the PUT request in android app

Tags: java, android, curl, put, netcat

I'm developing an Android app that supposed to send **PUT** request to  local server and when I try the same request using curl, I get success response, but from the Android app I get error with **PUT** request, here is the request for both from mobile app and curl, I listened to both requests on my PC using netcat

```
user@Laptop:~$ nc -l 192.168.1.104 55555
PUT /api/relay/0 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.104:55555
User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 31
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

apikey=2E5DE48567FB10F2&value=1


user@Laptop:~$ nc -l 192.168.1.104 55555
PUT /api/relay/0 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 9; HRY-LX1MEB Build/HONORHRY-LX1MEB)
Host: 192.168.1.104:55555
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 31

apikey=2E5DE48567FB10F2&value=1
```

here is my android java request

```
public void jsonRequestVolley(int method, String url, String requestBody) {         
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context); 

        JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(   
                method,                           
                url,                                            
                requestBody,
                successResponse(),  
                errorResponse()   
        )  
        {

            /**
             * Passing some request headers
             * */
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                return headers;
            }

        };

        queue.add(jsonRequest);
    }
```

the working curl command is

````
curl -X PUT -H "Accept: application/json" http://192.168.1.105:55555/api/relay/0 --data "apikey=2E5DE48567FB10F2&value=1"```
````

Comment: With a quick look, they are not the same requests at all, one has Content-Type of form data and the other json content type. That header matters, because the web service you are hitting may not be able to accept that content type. Also, what status code is returned when the call fails? Usually the status code returned indicates the nature of the problem.

Comment: the error code is Unexpected response code 404

Comment: I tried to mimic the curl request content but with no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the header because of local server requirements so, it worked now it look like

```
PUT /api/relay/0 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 9; HRY-LX1MEB Build/HONORHRY-LX1MEB)
Host: 192.168.1.104:55555
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 31
```

I added the following to Android code

```
@Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();

                headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                return headers;
            }

@Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            }
```

all in request code.